# How to trigger Enter Key Function in Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I ran in to a situation where sometimes clicking on a Submit button doesn't work in Selenium Webdriver. The same functionality could be obtained by pressing the Enter button.

Here, after entering the value in text box, I want Selenium WebDriver to press Enter key. How would I do that?
I'm using java

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("testing@netexam.com");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("testing@netexam.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); //Send Enter Key
```